Why can't I use the breadcrumb to navigate back in this highcharts treemap?
I have a treemap that defines a series that drills down into two series defined in drilldown. Drilling down works, but when I click the breadcrumb to try to navigate back nothing happens. There's probably something I haven't set up correctly, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLwpa0uf/
Code:
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'treemap'
    },
    series: [{
          id: "client",
        name: 'Client',
        data: [{
            drilldown: "10",
            id: "10",
            name: 'Client 10',
            value: 1184
        }, {
            drilldown: "BE",
            id: "BE",
            name: 'Client BE',
            value: 647
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
          id: '10',
          name: 'attribute_id',
            data: [
                {
                id: "10||CF  ",
                name: "Attr CF  ",
                parent: "10",
                value: 1184
                }
            ]
        }, {
          id: 'BE',
          name: 'attribute_id',
            data: [
                {
                id: "BE||BF  ",
                name: "Attr BF  ",
                parent: "BE",
                value: 647
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
});


When using a treemap series in Highcharts, it's better to use the levels mechanism rather than the drilldown module.
Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fjr5gpza/


Highcharts.chart("container", {
  series: [
    {
      type: "treemap",
      layoutAlgorithm: "squarified",
      allowDrillToNode: true,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      levelIsConstant: false,
      levels: [
        {
          level: 1,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          borderWidth: 3,
        },
      ],
      data: [
        {
          id: "A",
          name: "Category A",
          color: "#EC2500",
        },
        {
          id: "B",
          name: "Category B",
          color: "#ECE100",
        },
        {
          id: "C",
          name: "Category C",
          color: "#EC9800",
        },
        {
          name: "Subcategory A1",
          parent: "A",
          value: 6,
        },
        {
          name: "Subcategory A2",
          parent: "A",
          value: 4,
        },
        {
          name: "Subcategory B1",
          parent: "B",
          value: 4,
        },
        {
          name: "Subcategory B2",
          parent: "B",
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "Subcategory C1",
          parent: "C",
          value: 4,
        },
        {
          name: "Subcategory C2",
          parent: "C",
          value: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  title: {
    text: "Treemap with Drilldown",
  },
})
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>




Thank you. You say better. Do you know if the drilldown module no longer supported for treemap? While we probably could go this way, this is sadly not the json format of the data we are receiving, so it would mean some ugly tweaking to transform it to this model. We used to run highcharts 9 in which the drilldown module worked fine with treemaps. This issue started appearing after upgrading to highcharts 12.

Sure thing, I noticed that allowDrillToNode option was missing, and when we set it to true the breadcrumb works correctly again. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3opx7kwa/

That's great to hear!
